# Run a Python Script on Login with Sudo

Tags: command-line, python, login, scripts, sudo

I am setting up a machine that's sole purpose is to run a specific python application that uses a curses ui. That being said, there are some aspects of the application that require it to be run as su.

How can I run this application on login so the user doesn't need to execute it every time? I have seen [Is there a script that runs as root when user logs in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272919/is-there-a-script-that-runs-as-root-when-user-logs-in) and it seems different than mine as they don't actually require su there.

I really don't care about security at all for this application, it's not online nor will it ever be online. I don't even care if I have to enter my credentials twice either. I just want it to execute the line:

`sudo python ~/Application/main.py`

on login. If there's a more efficient way where I don't have to enter credentials twice, that would be even better. This has to work on Ubuntu Server as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution through this stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128817/how-can-i-execute-a-command-when-i-first-login-to-my-unix-server
which works for me. I just added

`cd ~/Application`
`sudo python main.py`