# Run a script with root privileges, but only at very first login of any user

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, login

How can I run a script that requires root privileges at login of a (or any) user?

I am building an Ubuntu 16.04 Docker image. I need to update the list of libraries with the `ldconfig -v` command but during the docker build process the hardware is not accessible therefore not all libraries will be added so I would like to run the command at the first login of a user.

Is there a directory maybe, from where scripts are executed at login events? Like /etc/init or /etc/init.d for start up.

Comment: Not sure what the script should do, so to get this correctly: does this script need to run on first login of either which user, then never again (so in total a single time), on first login *per user* or everytime the user (any) logs in? All can be done.

Comment: @JacobVlijm The script would contain a single line of useful code: `ldconfig -v`. It needs to run at first logon and never again. This is a docker image, with a single user so both options are good: for all users or for this single user, let's say the user **peter**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a script that runs as root when user logs in?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272919/is-there-a-script-that-runs-as-root-when-user-logs-in)

Comment: @M.Becerra not exactly, this script only needs to run *once*. The linked dupe is only one part of that.

Comment: Hi Peter, re- reading your question, I assume the command is not specific to login, is it? You could make it (as part of a few-lines script) run from `rc.local` (`script &`), with the condition a marker file does *not* exist, make it create the marker on first run. Then it will only run a single time. Would that work? Please mention.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm afraid not. This runs inside a docker container. So there are no such start-up steps executed when the docker is started.

Comment: Aha, obviously, my knowledge needs an upgrade. Thanks!